# execute do_shortcode in functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to run a do_shortcode in functions.php with no luck

I'm using Types plugin http://wp-types.com/ for creating custom post types and custom fields.

What I'm trying do is adding a custom column in admin for view all custom posts that displays a thumbnail from a custom field.

This is what I got so far, but it seems that the shortcode doesn't work inside functions.php

```
// add a column for custom post type (products)
add_filter('manage_product_posts_columns', 'add_thumbnail_column');
add_action('manage_product_posts_custom_column', 'add_thumbnail_content', 10, 2);

function add_thumbnail_column($defaults)
{
    $newSlice = array('thumbnail' => 'Image preview');
    $counter = 2;
    $array_head = array_slice($defaults,0,$counter);
    $array_tail = array_slice($defaults,$counter);
    $defaults = array_merge($array_head, $newSlice);
    $defaults = array_merge($defaults, $array_tail);
    return $defaults;  
}

function add_thumbnail_content($column_name, $post_ID)
{
    // this one works when putting into post content
    echo do_shortcode('[types field="square-picture" id="' . $post_ID . '" size="thumbnail"]' . '[/types]');
}
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

In the Wordpress notes for the function it says

> "If there are no shortcode tags defined, then the content will be
>   returned without any filtering. This might cause issues if a plugin is
>   disabled as its shortcode will still show up in the post or content."

Types may be conditionally declaring their short code only when you are on the frontend. What may be happening is that, in the admin, the short code is not defined and you are simply getting a false return. While on the frontend, the shortcode is defined and you get the results you intended.